# Reset/clear row based on selection/desection of checkbox in ui-grid angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

How do I reset the row based on selection of checkbox? I have the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/byxUjeUobaVmtIcgFUHS?p=preview) which I have to add the selection or checkbox where I can reset the fields.

```
$scope.gridStore.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    //set gridApi on scope
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != oldValue) {
            rowEntity.State = true;
            alert("selecetd");
        } 
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take a look at the example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/PIBpUWD47ayEYAVxlfP3?p=preview) and make changes accordingly.

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
    var rows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();

    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
    var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
    $scope.rowtobebinded=row.entity.ITEMNO;
  });
```